# How can I add custom Frame objects to custom ttk Notebook in Tkinter/python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tabs, frame

I am creating a Tkinter/Python3 application where the main window inherits from `Notebook` (i need tabs), and each tab should be a custom class inheriting from `Frame` (I would then dynamically use `matplotlib` to create custom graphs).
Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to have `Notebook` accept my custom `Frames`.
Following very reduced snippet of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook

class MyFrame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, mytext=""):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.create_widgets(mytext)

    def create_widgets(self, mytext):
        self.label =  Label(self.master, text=mytext, anchor=W)
        # this is not placed relative to the Frame, but to the
        # master
        # 1. How I get the relative coordinates inside the frame
        #    to be 10, 10 of the frame area?
        self.label.place(x=10, y=10, width=128, height=24)

class MyNotebook(Notebook):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.f1 = MyFrame1(self, "abc")
        # once the UI is drawn, the label "def" seems to overlay
        # "abc" even when "f1" is selected
        # 2. Why is self.f2 always shown even when self.f1 is
        #    selected?
        self.f2 = MyFrame1(self, "def")
        self.add(self.f1, text="f1")
        self.add(self.f2, text="f2")
        # Without this command nothing gets drawn
        # 3. Why is this? Is this equivalent of 'pack' but for 
        #    pixel driven layout?
        self.place(width=640, height=480)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.minsize(640, 480)
    root.geometry("640x480")
    app = MyNotebook(master=root)
    # this works as intended the label is indeed placed
    # in the frame at 10, 10
    #app = MyFrame1(master=root, mytext="123abc")
    app.mainloop()
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As per comments I have the following main question: why aren't my custom instances of `MyFrame1` properly displayed inside `MyNotebook`?

Sub questions:

1. How can I get relative coordinate areas of where the frame is located when `place` my elements (in this case a `Label`)?
2. Why even when `self.f1` tab is selected in the UI, I can still see the content of `self.f2` tab?
3. Is `self.place` required in order to show all sub-elements when not using `pack`?
4. If I dynamically create Tkinter elements after the `MyNotebook` is initialized, will those be bound to respective tabs?

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Your `create_widgets` method needs to add widgets to `self`, not `self.master`.

> How can I get relative coordinate areas of where the frame is located when place my elements (in this case a Label)?

I don't understand what you mean by this. When you use `place`, coordinates will be interpreted relative to the frame. However, I strongly advise against using `place`. Both `pack` and `grid` will trigger the frame to resize to fit its children which almost always results in a more responsive UI

> Why even when self.f1 tab is selected in the UI, I can still see the content of self.f2 tab?

Because you added internal widgets to `self.master` instead of `self`.

> Is self.place required in order to show all sub-elements when not using pack?

No. It is required to use a geometry manager but it doesn't have to be `place`. Usually, `place` is the least desirable geometry manager to use. `pack` and `grid` are almost always better choices except for some very specific situations.

> If I dynamically create Tkinter elements after the MyNotebook is initialized, will those be bound to respective tabs?

They will be in whatever tab you put them in.

---

Finally, I would suggest that you remove `self.place` in `create_widgets`. Instead, call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` in the same block of code that creates an instance of that class.

It's a bad practice for a widget to add itself to another widget's layout. The code that creates the widget should be the code that adds the widget to the layout.

Comment: Thanks it was a silly mistake at my end.